# Can't display image in JSP

Tags: jsp

I try to create project in eclipse.
My images are located in WebContent/images folder.
I get access to the image like with :

```html
<body>
     <%  
        List<String> images =  (List<String>)application.getAttribute("images");
        for(String image: images){
             
     %> 
        <img src="<%=application.getContextPath()%>/java1.png" width="150" height="200"/>
        <p><%=application.getContextPath()%>/images/java1.png</p>
     <% }%>
      
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Is the image not found at the inserted path or is no image path inserted?

Comment: Path is correct, but image is not displayed. Instead of image - the empty frame

Comment: So if you rightclick the image and open it in an own tab, it's visible?

Comment: the image location in eclipse project - /projectname/WebContent/images/image.png.  I point it like this - application.getAttribute(...), which is set in deployement descriptor.

Comment: it is visible in images folder, but not in browser

Comment: Then you need the solution of Neeraj Jain. I don't see why this should not be secure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to access the image file

Instead of using this

```
application.getContextPath();
```

Use this

```
application.getRealPath("/");
```

The application.getRealPath() converts a web content path (the path in the expanded WAR folder structure on the server's disk file system) to an absolute disk file system path.

The `"/"` represents the web content root .

Comment: Thank you . It works, but it is not secure , i think.